# Installation of scilab-5.5.2

Tags: software-installation, scilab

Whenever I tried to use install Scilab-5.5.2 by

```
sudo apt-get install scilab
```

its asking

```
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

while form Ubuntu software centre it is giving response faulty internet connection.

please help me

Comment: Are you sure you have Internet connection?

Comment: Did you try `apt-get update` as suggested by the error message? What's its output?

Answer (score 0):

The proposed repository you should only use if you are able to solve problems. The latest scilab version in the offical Ubuntu repositories is 5.5.1

Open the file `sources.list`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and comment out the line that contains `proposed` with a `#`, eg:

```
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-proposed multiverse restricted universe main
```

Then run this commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scilab
```